# Confused as to what this firebase rule means? Data not displaying from firestore database

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

The rule is

```
match /{document=**} {
  allow read, write: if request.time <= timestamp.date(2022, 1, 31);
}
```

Does it mean that read and write permissions are valid only till Jan 31 2022?
The data is not displaying in UI anymore.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, as long as `request.time <= timestamp.date(2022, 1, 31)` is true, users can read and write to Firestore. Those are the default rules so just in case you forget to secure your database, access will be denied after that time. You can always update that and extend the data or even better write security rules that match your needs.

Checkout [Security rules - Get to know Cloud Firestore](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eW5MdE3ZcAw)